# Polygon covers some part of the footprint

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, polygon

I am using Eagle for PCB and can't solve this issue. Polygon gets inside the footprint. I tried changing isolate and width parameters but the larger the distance or width, the more airwire errors pop up because grounds aren't connected to each other. I am new to PCB so I may not know where the polygon properties are but I could not find this property.

[image]

Comment: Why are you bothered by the fill under the component? If you really worry, throw in a keepout zone.

Comment: It's because I'm going to make PCB myself and am worried about shorts, thank you btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a small `41 tRestrict` polygon where you don't want fill.